# AppBarLayout won't scroll to focused EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a layout where `EditText` is inside `AppBarLayout`. If user clicks on `EditText`, keyboard is shown but the layout won't scroll to make `EditText` visible. Normally, if `EditText` would be in `ScrollView`, it would scroll so that `EditText` is above the keyboard. It doesn't happen in this case.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is there a way to scroll the layout manually so that `EditText` won't hide under the keyboard?
Also, if `EditText` is multiline, how to scroll to where cursor is, not where the view top is (when `EditText` size is wrap content it will change it height if multiline, and normally view would scroll so that cursor is always visible, which is not the case here).

**Edit:**

Input mode is set to `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and I cannot change it to `adjustPan` because some parts of the layout are obscured when keyboard is present (e.g. activity's toolbar)

Comment: I think this may help you.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft

Comment: Yes, I tried changing `android:windowSoftInputMode`, but I can't do it, because it makes layout look weird and some parts of it move and they shouldn't (it is now set to adjustResize).